# How do you make a link inside a PropertyColumn in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

I successfully made an AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable, but I want to make the contents of the cells links.  How do I do this with Apache Wicket?

Answer (score 7):

You can use an `AbstractColumn` instead of a `PropertyColumn`. This will allow you to add whatever component you like, rather than just the string value of the PropertyModel.

```
columns.add(new AbstractColumn("displayModel", "sortModel") {
   void populateItem(Item cellItem, String componentId, IModel rowModel) {
      cellItem.add(new LinkPanel(componentId, rowModel));
   }
}
```

Where `LinkPanel` is the component you want to add in the cell.