# How can I add an image column to a table in wicket framework?

Tags: java, wicket

I want to add a column containing images in each cell of a table in wicket framework. I make the table in a java class and have a createColumns() method as the following:

```
private List<IColumn> createColumns() {
    List<IColumn> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn>();
    // Create the columns that will be displayed, second param is the sort
    // order
    // Use column position for aggregate functions
    // Otherwise the query uses column aliases so these need to match here

    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model("Status"), "code") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item item, String componentId, IModel model) {
            Object[] values = ((ArrayWrapper) model.getObject()).getArray();
            setStatus((Integer) values[0]);
            item.add(new Image(componentId, new ResourceReference(this.getClass(), getStatus())));
        }
    });

    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model("First"), "2", "array[1]"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model("Last"), "3", "array[2]"));        
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model("Sender"), "sender",
            "array[4]"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model("Receiver"), "receiver",
            "array[5]"));

    columns.add(new HeaderlessColumn() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void populateItem(Item cellItem, String componentId,
                IModel rowModel) {
            cellItem.add(new ActionPanel(componentId, rowModel));
        };
    });

    return columns;
}
```

The html file is simply as the following:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.sourceforge.net/">
<body>
<wicket:extend>
 <table align="center" wicket:id="results"></table>
</wicket:extend>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get an exception which is:

> org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Component cell must be applied to a tag of type 'img', not '' (line 0, column 0)

And it's related to the lines that I make the column for image. Can anyone help me how I can make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in CreateColumns method is as the following:

```
   columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model("Status"), "code") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item item, String componentId, IModel model) {
            Object[] values = ((ArrayWrapper) model.getObject()).getArray();
            setStatus((Integer) values[0]);
            item.add(new ImagePanel(componentId, new ResourceReference(SearchResults.class, getStatus())));
        }
    });
```

And this is the ImagePanel:

```
 public class ImagePanel extends Panel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * @param id
     */
    public ImagePanel(String id, ResourceReference image) {
        super(id);
        add(new Image("status", image));
    }
}
```

The html code for the panel is:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.sourceforge.net/">
<body>
<wicket:panel>
<img wicket:id="status"/>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has no sense using `PropertyColumn` here. The second parameter you're passing as `propertyName` is useless because you're overriding the only method that is using it, `populateItem()`, anyway (which is the only extension that `PropertyColumn` provides to `AbstractColumn`), and therefore overriding the whole purpose of `PropertyColumn`. You should be using `AbstractColumn`.

Answer (score 5):

Use an [`AbstractColumn`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/tree/table/AbstractColumn.html) instead of a `PropertyColumn`. `PropertyColumn` is suitable if you only need to specify a property name, as you would do with a `PropertyModel`.

From [this discussion](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/difference-between-ListView-and-DefaultDataTable-td1855270.html) in the Wicket users list, `DataTable` outputs this markup:

```
<tbody> 
  <tr wicket:id="rows"> 
    <td wicket:id="cells"> 
      <span wicket:id="cell">[cell]</span> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Note that [`IColumn`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/IColumn.html) implements [`ICellPopulator`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/grid/ICellPopulator.html), and it is `ICellPopulator#populateItem()` that is overriden in `AbstractColumn`.

So, whatever you come up with in `populateItem` should be ok if associated with a `<span>` in markup. `PropertyColumn` might be doing it with a Label, and you should be fine adding a custom `Panel` or `WebMarkupContainer` which will contain your `Image`.

This is a slightly related question: [How do you make a link inside a PropertyColumn in Wicket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2711190/851811)

Comment: @NoushinKhaki Glad it worked. Remember to upvote helpful answers and accept the one you think was the best.